# Add values to MatOfPoint variable in Java

Tags: java, opencv, double, getter-setter

I'm trying to convert a `double[][]` into a `MatOfPoint` of `OpenCV`. *pointsOrdered* is a `double[4][2]` with coordinates of four points in it.
I've tried with:

```
MatOfPoint sourceMat =  new MatOfPoint();
for (int idx = 0; idx < 4; idx++) {
    (sourceMat.get(idx, 0))[0] = pointsOrdered[idx][0];
    (sourceMat.get(idx, 0))[1] = pointsOrdered[idx][1];
}
```

but `sourceMat` values stay the same.
I'm trying to add values one by one as I haven't found other options.

What can I do? Is there a simple way to access and modify a `MatOfPoint` variable values?

Comment: What is the MatOfPoint data type, is this of type of OpenCV?

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten to say it, sorry. I've updated the question.

Comment: why are you using MatOfPoint ? you are not using Point typed inputs for MatOfPoint ?

Comment: I need to do a warp perspective transformation. I've seen that Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform requires a MatOfPoint variable containing spatially ordered points (that I have stored in the double[4][2]).

Comment: then your input values' type must be Point to store x,y in MatOfPoint, check my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint` expects `org.opencv.core.Point` objects but it stores Point's property values `(x,y)` not `Point` object's itself

if you convert your `double[][] pointsOrdered` array to `ArrayList<Point>`

```
ArrayList<Point> pointsOrdered = new ArrayList<Point>();
pointsOrdered.add(new Point(xVal, yVal));
...
```

then you can create  `MatOfPoint` from this `ArrayList<Point>`

```
MatOfPoint sourceMat = new MatOfPoint();
sourceMat.fromList(pointsOrdered);
//your sourceMat is Ready.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excessively complicated example answer to show what can be done that combines the use of lists/arrays/array lists (pick your poison) as recommended with what is really wrong and caused the question.  "Mat get" method and "Mat put" method had been confused - reversed in usage.

```java
MatOfPoint sourceMat=new MatOfPoint();

sourceMat.fromArray( // a recommended way to initialize at compile time if you know the values
                new Point(151., 249.),
                new Point(105., 272.),
                new Point(102., 318.),
                new Point(138., 337.));

// A way to change existing data or put new data if need be if you set the size of the MatOfPoints first
double[] corner=new double[(int)(sourceMat.channels())];// 2 channels for a point

for (int idx = 0; idx<sourceMat.rows(); idx++) {
     System.out.println((corner[0]=sourceMat.get(idx, 0)[0]) + ", " + (corner[1]=sourceMat.get(idx, 0)[1]));
     corner[0]+=12.; // show some change can be made to existing point.x
     corner[1]+=8.; // show some change can be made to existing point.y
     sourceMat.put(idx, 0, corner);
     System.out.println((corner[0]=(float)sourceMat.get(idx, 0)[0]) + ", " + (corner[1]=(float)sourceMat.get(idx, 0)[1]));
}
```